# Why does my Turtle writing appear different on mac and pc?

Tags: fonts, size, turtle-graphics

```
from turtle import *

def hospital():
    setheading(0)
    forward(55)
    pendown()
    color("black", "white")
    begin_fill()
    for _ in range(2):
        backward(130)
        right(90)
        backward(20)
        right(90)
    end_fill()
    penup()
    setheading(180)
    forward(105)
    write("HOSPITAL", font=("Verdana", 14, "bold"))

hospital()
```

When I run this on my mac the word 'HOSPITAL' fits perfectly inside the box.  However, when running this on my pc, 'HOSPITAL' is much larger and exceeds the box.  Why?

Answer (score 0):

Font size only specifies the height.  You've used a fixed width for your box, rather than actually measuring the amount of width the font needs.  And you're using a fixed height for your box, rather than compute the font's height as it appears on *your* screen.

Font height is measured in *points* but turtle only knows how to draw in *pixels*, so you also need to convert between the two.  Here's some code that attempts to measure as it draws boxed text:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

FONT_SIZE = 14
FONT = ('Verdana', FONT_SIZE, 'bold')

POSITION = (55, 0)

PIXELS_PER_INCH = 90  # set this based on *your* display
POINTS_PER_INCH = 72  # what the size of a font represents

X, Y = 0, 1

def box_text(turtle, text):

    start = marker.position()
    marker.write(text, align='center', move=True, font=FONT)
    end = marker.position()

    screen_font_size = PIXELS_PER_INCH * (FONT_SIZE / POINTS_PER_INCH)

    lower_left = (2 * start[X] - end[X], start[Y])
    upper_right = (end[X], start[Y] + screen_font_size)

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(lower_left)
    turtle.pendown()

    turtle.goto(upper_right[X], lower_left[Y])
    turtle.goto(upper_right)
    turtle.goto(lower_left[X], upper_right[Y])
    turtle.goto(lower_left)

    turtle.penup()

screen = Screen()

marker = Turtle(visible=False)
marker.penup()
marker.goto(POSITION)

box_text(marker, "HOSPITAL")

screen.mainloop()
```

I don't use a Windows system, so you'll need to confirm whether or not it draws something reasonable on both systems.  (Not something *identical*, just something *reasonable*!)  There are so many issues with fonts that I'm not sure if the above is sufficient.

[image]

You may want to add some padding to the text box depending on the needs of your application.